# VBA - Copy a template worksheet and rename with user entered text

Tags: vba, excel

VBA novice here - I've combed the interwebs and can't seem to get this to work, it's got me stumped.

I would like to have a button on a form that will allow a user to generate a copy of a worksheet "Template", in the same workbook - to the right of "Template". I've figured it out enough that I can generate a copy that renames itself as Template(2) OR generate a blank worksheet named with the text entered in the prompt, but I can't do both.

As is below - it currently returns an "Object Required" error. Thanks in advance for your help, it's much appreciated!

```
Private Sub NewSheet()
 Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
 Dim newName As String
 Do
 newName = Application.InputBox("What do you want to name the new sheet?", Type:=2)
If newName = "False" Then Exit Sub: Rem cancel pressed 

Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy(After:=Worksheets("Template"))

On Error Resume Next
    NewSheet.Name = newName
    newName = Error
On Error GoTo 0

If newName <> vbNullString Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        NewSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox newName
End If
Loop Until newName = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Template")
    Dim newws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, newname
    Dim query As Long, xst As Boolean, info As String

retry:
    xst = False
    newname = Application.InputBox("Enter a new sheet name.", info, , , , , , 2)
    If newname = "False" Then Exit Sub
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.Name = newname Then
            xst = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then
        info = "Sheet name is invalid. Please retry."
        GoTo retry
    End If
    ws.Copy after:=ws: Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.Name = newname
End Sub
```

This will continuously ask for a valid sheet name unless the user cancels it. 
To avoid deleting a newly added sheet, check first if the name is valid. 
Also, I don't think you can copy and assign in one go since there's no documentation that the *Copy Method* returns the object that was copied. So you copy first and use *Activesheet* to assign it to a variable.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! Makes sense about the Copy and Assign at once. Much appreciated.